# Is there a way to deinterlace footage using Blender?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video

I have a camera that has always seemed to give me bad video because of interlacing, and until I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKMWjRlIvrY), I always thought that it was just a limitation of the camera.

From that video, I learned that video can be deinterlaced, is it possible to this using Blender?

Comment: in the video sequence editor you have an option in the properties panel --> filter tab you can check de-interlace

Comment: @gladys That seems to do the trick. Thanks! Would you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the video sequence editor you have an option in the properties panel --> filter tab, you can check de-interlace.

[image]